# Getting an exception when working with directoryInfo in C# / XNA

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone

Think I have a problem with my windows phone application.
In my application I have a static method that returns me a collection of textures located in specific folder. When I launch my application on the WP 8 Emulator it`s worked very well, but when I launch it on the WP 7 emulator I get an exception with the message "directory not exist". But in fact that this directory is existing.
Could anybody tell me why this happends ?

Here I attached my code:

```
namespace Hornbook_v2
{
    public static class ContentLoader
    {
        public static Dictionary<String, T> LoadTextures<T>(this ContentManager contentManager, string contentFolder)
        {
            //Load directory info, abort if none
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(contentManager.RootDirectory + "\\" + contentFolder);

            //  The exception is happends HERE!!!
            if (!dir.Exists)
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();

            //Init the resulting list
            Dictionary<String, T> result = new Dictionary<String, T>();

            //Load all files that matches the file filter
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                string key = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);

                //result[key] = contentManager.Load<T>(contentManager.RootDirectory + "/" + contentFolder + "/" + key);
                result[key] = contentManager.Load<T>(contentFolder + "/" + key);
            }

            //Return the result
            return result;
        }    

    }
}
```

Comment: and what IS the exact directory?

Comment: I pass to this method the next string "Screens/ShowScreen/Letters"

Comment: This might be of interest: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/sample/contentmanifestextensions It's an example of a content pipeline extensiont to allow you to get a list of all content at build time and access it at runtime. I've used it (and extended it a lot) to great effect.

Comment: May be exising some specific way to avoid rewriting a half of program? ))

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the IsolatedStorage API, even if just for that one DirectoryExists check [this](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-files-and-folders):

EDIT

If you do need to port it all to IsolatedStorage, [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd5e2z84%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) may be of use: